# javascript on VScode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I copy the code from my udemy course. But the result is totally different. Nothing shows on my website. Can anyone tell me what wrong it is?

[html_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUiqX.jpg)
[js_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D79Eo.jpg)
[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e48G.png)

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: "Hello World" should be shown on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows me an issue with the script tag. It should be src attribute, not scr.
I am attaching an image displayed to me on the above-mentioned link.[Image displayed to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN6Vd.png)